# Combination of two DataFrames with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to combine the columns of two dataframes (with very large numbers of entries) such that one column of the first DF is the index of the other.

To explain, here is some example code

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4'],
'Feature': ['Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3', 'Feature2'],
},index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Feature': ['Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3'],
'Property1': ['Property11', 'Property12', 'Property13'],
'Property2': ['Property21', 'Property22', 'Property23']},index=[0, 1, 2])
df2.set_index('Feature', inplace=True)
```

I expect the output to be like this

```
    ID   Feature    Property1    Property2
0   ID1  Feature1   Property11   Property21
1   ID2  Feature2   Property12   Property22
2   ID3  Feature3   Property13   Property23
3   ID4  Feature2   Property11   Property22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple merge

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='Feature', right_index=True)

Out[264]:
    ID   Feature   Property1   Property2
0  ID1  Feature1  Property11  Property21
1  ID2  Feature2  Property12  Property22
3  ID4  Feature2  Property12  Property22
2  ID3  Feature3  Property13  Property23
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the index of the other data frame to the column you want to join on and then reset the index:

```
df_result = df2.join(df1.set_index('Feature')).reset_index()
```